# Can't access component controls in a .NET Windows.Form.Control custom control in a sub-Namespace

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, custom-controls

I've been building a custom control library in .NET and have a number of related controls and supporting classes that I'd like to group together in a namespace, under my library's root namespace.  When I add the namespace definition to the code behind of the first control, it loses access to the controls that it's made from.

```
Namespace Advanced
    Public Class AdvancedSelector
        Private _ItemType As Type
        Public Property ItemType As Type
            Get
                Return _ItemType
            End Get
            Set(value As Type)
                _ItemType = value

                'build our datagridview columns from type info
                Dim availableColumns As New List(Of DataGridViewColumn)

...


                'assuming that we got this far, assign the new columns to their respective controls
                dgvAvailable.DataSource = Nothing
                dgvAvailable.Columns.Clear()
                dgvAvailable.Columns.AddRange(availableColumns.ToArray)

                dgvSelected.DataSource = Nothing
                dgvSelected.Columns.Clear()
                dgvSelected.Columns.AddRange(selectedColumns.ToArray)
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

When I add `Namespace Advanced ... End Namespace`, my code suddenly can't access dgvAvailable and dgvSelected.  As these are subcontrols that are part of my custom control class, I'm not sure why they didn't end up under the same new namespace.  Do I have to go into the Designer file and force the issue?  Is that even possible?

Comment: The designer files for you custom controls will have partial class that link to the code behind.  Any namespace chance you make needs to be replicated in both

Comment: Thank you.  That worked. If you set make your answer into a comment, I will happily upvote it.